# Java Project Architecture Samples

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, architecture

What is the best book, source for designing a good project architecture based on Java, JEE, Rest, Spring etc. I know all of the technologies and best practices pretty well, but there is no one who can give me a feed back on the architectural issues of my app. Especially when it comes to concurrency and multi threading part, I am always doubtful if this is the best way to solve the problems. Unfortunately, I search the INTERNET and can't find any sample, or reference projects that focuses on the architecture rather than a specific tech. only. E.g. you can find millions of articulates on rest, but nothing on how you should deal with multithreading in a restful env. etc. If you can suggest any books, materials, or reference code, I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The  book I found useful is

1> Enterprise Integration patterns by Martin Fowler

2> Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz

3> Clean Code By Uncle BOB

It will help if you are working on legacy systems and try to find best possible architecture for your application. There is no general one fits all size kind of book or blog which can be put down. The architectural decisions are very specific to the application you have designed. The best way is not to really think about what to anticipate very early but keep it flexible enough for the change based on open closed principle.

Take an example of an application you are about to develop and you are still not sure of the kind of network topology your infrastructure team is going to set i.e. either  a round robin load balancer or sticky sessions. This will very much drive the code you have to write for certain functionalities such as authentication. So you can keep that part of authentication functionality configurable in your code so that you can effectively switch to the final topology. This is just an example and you have to keep certain things in mind but not overdoing this.

One more example can be of caching mechanism you want to use. Whether you should keep thin sin httpsession(which is not recommended) or use some  persistent/distributed cache to store your data.

These are examples which is very specific to your application and you should ask all sort of questions to your stakeholders.

With the advent of java 8  you can apply certain concepts of functional programming to get rid of concurrency issues. You cannot do that on legacy projects but start to apply them on your green field projects .Again the architecture of your project keeps evolving based on the feasible approaches you are going to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the books.  Have read the first two already, third one is new. Checking out it right away.